# Restricting textarea to add text more than it's height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, css

I have a `textarea` of fixed `width` and `height`, I don't want to resize `textarea` neither I want to add scroller to it, when text greater than it's height is added. I want it to restrict adding further text.

Note: `maxLength` property will not solve my problem, as `fontSize` and `fontFamily` can be anything, so I don't know `maxLength` value, only `width` and `height` of `textarea` in pixels

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```js
$("#test1").on("keypress", function(event) {    
    if(($(this).prop("scrollHeight")) > $(this).innerHeight()){
      
      return false;
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test1" rows="2"></textarea>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for pasting content with the mouse.

Comment: Bind the paste event and perform the same. you have to another function after pasting it cut the text until scroll height reaches to inner height of element.
Hope this info will help you i guess.

Comment: When I'll try to add character in between it will remove the already added character from end. Also the user experience is not so nice. Is there any way to do it with css?

Comment: @RohitSaini If you add character in between it make textarea to  get scroll so it will remove last character as per logic. Use keypress event and check if you add this character to textarea is it become scrollable then return false.

Comment: @RohitSaini I modified the code please have look it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <textarea rows="3" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
a
</textarea>

  <script>
    function myFunction(textarea) {
      if (textarea.scrollHeight > textarea.clientHeight) {
        console.log('visible')
      } else {
        console.log('not visible');
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving me the hint. I was looking for a solution in React, but the solution in Jquery helped too. So,I am writing solution to my own question in react

```
enter code here

onPaste(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  ev.preventDefault();
  const elem = this.textarea;
  const clipboardData = ev.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  const pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
  let index = elem.selectionStart;
  for (let i=0; i<pastedData.length; i++) {
    const strChar = pastedData.charAt(i);
    elem.value = elem.value.slice(0, index) + strChar + elem.value.slice(index);
    if (this.textarea && elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight) {
      elem.value = elem.value.slice(0, index) + elem.value.slice(index + 1);
      break;
    }
    index = index + 1;
  }
}

handleTextareaChange(ev) {
  const elem = this.textarea;
  if (elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight) {
    elem.value = elem.value.slice(0, elem.selectionStart - 1) + elem.value.slice(elem.selectionStart);
   }
}



React JSX

<textarea
    title={this.props.tooltip}
    onChange={this.handleTextareaChange}
    onPaste={this.onPaste}
    ref={textarea => {
       this.textarea = textarea;
    }}
    style={{overflowY: "hidden"}}
  />
```